# Points not getting added for voted up question

Tags: support, questions, up-votes

On gamedevelopment.stackexchange i have added the following question:
["Most useful free third party Android Game libraries?"](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/12571/most-useful-free-third-party-android-game-libraries)

As of now it has been voted up 4 times. However, my points are still the same. They are not increasing. What should I do? What help can I get?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That question has been changed to a community wiki question by a moderator, so nobody gets rep.

Comment: ok. Havent noticed that earlier.Thanks!

Comment: @GamDroid be sure to mark this answer as "accepted" then.